# Отобразить прогресс запроса к серверу C#

Tags: c#, async-await

Отправляю асинхронный запрос к серверу следующим образом:

```
string checkpoint = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        string sha = ApiLitres.ComputeSha256Hash(unixTimestamp + ":SECRETKYEY:" + checkpoint);
        string place = "****";

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "checkpoint", checkpoint },
           { "place", place },
           { "timestamp", unixTimestamp.ToString() },
           { "sha", sha }
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://partnersdnld.litres.ru/get_fresh_book/", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Если, например, делаю выборку за пару последних дней, то результат возвращается за пару секунд. Но если выборка будет за пару месяцев, то придется подождать. Вот и хочется отобразить прогресс в pgogressBar, чтобы наверняка знать сколько ждать.
Результат в виде списка книг возвращается в XML.

Comment: Оффтоп, но все же, используйте [`DateTimeOffset::ToUnixTimeSeconds()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_ToUnixTimeSeconds)

Comment: А как вы его сделаете, если сам сервер (как я понимаю) обрабатывает долго данные и из за этого висит запрос? Делайте тогда по одной дате сами, тогда будет минимальная дата, максимальная и общее кол-во, вот уже вам и прогресс бар.

Comment: Не факт что сервер вообще отправляет заголовок `Content-Length`. Возможно он просто на лету отправляет данные, тогда вы никак не можете точно знать, сколько байт занимает тела ответа.

Comment: это обычно делается асинхронно на основе веб сокетов с периодической отправкой результатов с сервера на клиент о текущем прогрессе.